# Page numbers on margin KOMA-Script

Tags: page-numbering, koma-script

How to put page number on a margin aligned with first line of a text?

Comment: And on pages with headings? What about headlines? Which page layout?

Comment: Or the page number aligned with the position position of the text area? Your question (to is seems simple to you) is very very unclear.

Comment: Look on the right side of this page and you will find several related questions, which might have a useful answer already.